# Apache available on LAN but get timeout over internet

Tags: apache-2.2, routing, nat

I have a LAN network and a server runs on 192.168.1.90
The apache listen parameter is set to 192.168.1.90:80
I have enabled NAT to forward all http port 80 request from the web to the server at 192.168.1.90

for a different machine 192.168.1.3 I can access the server by typing in 192.168.1.90 in the browser address bar. But when I make a request from an external network over the internet using my external IP ie: 122.109.x.107 The browser just says connecting and never connects.

The last entry of my access log

```
    192.168.1.3 - - [07/Jan/2013:19:08:57 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 502 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0"
164.106.234.73 - - [07/Jan/2013:20:36:32 +0530] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
112.79.41.205 - - [07/Jan/2013:21:16:33 +0530] "\xc8\x99\x84:\xbc\xe5@\xf7\xd6\xf1\xd5&\xdag\xc9\x05\t\x11I4\xb0t\xc1xZ}\x06\xa6\xef\x16R\xe3\x88\x92\x8a\xb7\xc0\x10\xc9B26\x80:\x86!\xa4\xcc};bwb\x83\xe0\xe3m=\xc4" 400 322 "-" "-"
211.136.115.11 - - [07/Jan/2013:21:30:36 +0530] "\xc2\x8e\x14\x7fX\x93\xc7\xb9\x7f\x9b\xbeEd\xf8:\xb4uB\x0f\xbb`r\x18F\x91\xd3>\xfeM\xab\x94]\xd9es\xfa\xbf\xf5\x80\xe2t\\\xdc\x86E\x8c\bO(\xa7yo\xc6\xc1/\vs\xe8" 400 322 "-" "-"
```

**NOTE: New requests are not getting added, tried few more times after this, those are not in the log**

I am getting a connection timed out after some time

Comment: Do you have a firewall in front of your web server? Is the routing table correct on the web server?

Comment: iptables set to allow all traffic, both on the server and the browsing system

Comment: Can you post the output of `iptables -n -L` on both machines? Also, please post the output of `route -n` on the web server.

Comment: Here is the out put > http://pastebin.com/DXpHkuzM

Comment: Can you please paste the output for `iptables -L -n -t nat`

Comment: Output for `iptables -L -n -t nat` >> http://pastebin.com/vW71XUFP

Comment: Do you have ip forwarding enabled? Output of `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` should be 1.

Comment: Yes it is 1 on the server. My router is set to NAT web requests to the server

Answer (score 0):

Ok at last figure it out, was issue with iptables firewall. 
I just reset the entire firewall and then used my own rules :)

you can use webmin if you need a gui, I personally prefer the terminal.